# Scaling a video down to 24x15 resolution

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, scale

I've made a 24x15 LED display running off an Arduino, and last year I put 32KB of graphics routines in memory, and it was cool.

But now I've upgraded to the Arduino Mega, with 256KB memory, and have a 'music shield' which has an micro-SD card reader.

So my new plan is to play animation off of the SD card.

I have written a routine to load a buffer onto my 24x15 display.

So I want to store screen-captured (or any) video animation on disk, using simple 3 byte RGB pixels.  The algorithm would be to take an interpolation of any resolution, picking an average colour of each (height/15 and width/24) block.  So a 24x15 animation would be the special edge case of this scenario.  640x480 will obviously look ridiculous scaled down, but I could probably get Mario looking characters looking pretty good.

Any ideas about how to do this?  Has anyone written this before?  I'm sure someone has.  But it's really hard to find.

Comment: You should be able to get that working with [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html), but it won't look great.

Comment: What sort of format/codec could I use, that I'd be able to read it back out into the component colours on the Arduino side?  I don't have the stomach for reading RFCs, so I'm looking for existing libraries.  Otherwise, I am going for my own format.

Comment: At that frame size? Anything.

Answer (score 1):

[`QuickASCII`](http://quickascii.sourceforge.net) "is a console-based movie player and picture viewer powered by Quicktime" that illustrates how you can leverage Quicktime for this on supported platforms.

Comment: It's a cool piece of code, but unfortunately I need to play the generated movie off an Arduino.

Comment: I was thinking you could use the decoded, resampled quicktime output to fill your LED buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Uncompressed AVI is an easy format to read on an Arduino and the pixels are RGB. So you could use AVIsynth or any video tool that can write AVI to transcode your source video from any format and size that your tool can read to 24x15 AVI uncompressed, then transfer that to an SD card for the Arduino to read and playback on the RGB LEDs. You don't have to write an AVI reader that can read *any* kind of AVI, just one that can read the specific flavor that your video tools writes (e.g., hardcode starting offsets and byte counts, etc.)

Alternatively, have the video tool write a numbered "image sequence" of .BMP files, which are also easy to read (again, especially if you only have to read one flavor). I've done that for video-like playback on embedded devices before.

Note: Make sure your video tool is using a good scaling algorithm so the 24x15 pixels represent accumulated areas of source pixels and not simple point sampling, which will cause bad aliasing artifacts. You can also try applying some Gaussian blur to the original video before the massive downscaling it order to prevent aliasing.

References:

AVI file format:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318189(v=vs.85).aspx
http://yaai.sourceforge.net/yaai/fileformat.html

BMP file format:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

AVI Synth: 
http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Main_Page

Sony Movie Studio Platinum Trial (for encoding uncompressed AVI files):
http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/download/trials/moviestudiope